# Maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/ (x^2 + y^2 -1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> I need to show that the ideal $(\overline{x},\overline{y} -1 )$ is maximal in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/ (x^2 + y^2 -1)$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A ideal $I$ is maximal in a ring $A$ if and only if $A/I$ is a field. So try computing the quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Set $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/ (x^2 + y^2 -1)$. Then $R/(\overline{x},\overline{y} -1 )\simeq\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x,y-1)$.